# How to inject/use a service inside forRoot()

Tags: angular, google-maps

I have an angular projet, I import a NguiMapModule in AppModule and passing a value of apiUrl from the environment file `NguiMapModule.forRoot({apiUrl: environment.gmaps_url}),` .

**my question is how can I pass  pass the gmaps_url from my ConfigService,** it load data from json file

AppModule:

```
    export function  load(http: HttpClient, config: ConfigService): (() => Promise<boolean>) {
 return (): Promise<boolean> => {
   return new Promise<boolean>((resolve: (a: boolean) => void): void => {
     http.get('./config.json')
       .pipe(
         map((x: ConfigService) => {
   ....
           config.gmaps_url=  x.gmaps_api_uri;
           resolve(true);
         }),
         catchError((x: { status: number }, caught: Observable<void>): ObservableInput<{}> => {
           if (x.status !== 404) {
             resolve(false);
           }
...
           config.gmaps_url= 'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js;
         
           resolve(true);
           return of({});
         })
       ).subscribe();
   });
 };
}
...
providers: [
....,
 {
     provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
     useFactory: load,
     multi: true,
     deps: [
       HttpClient,
       ConfigService
     ]
   },
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo you can found in this [Stackbitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3pb1eu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapi.service.ts)

Basically, for providing apiUrl rather than module file, You need to extend injection token provided by library.. for example inside your main component app.component.ts we inject token like below code..

```
constructor(
             @Inject(NG_MAP_CONFIG_TOKEN) apiToken: ConfigOption,
             private apiService: ApiService
           ){
                 apiToken.apiUrl = this.apiService.getAPiUrl();
                 this.apiToken = apiToken.apiUrl;
            }
```

We provide api url from service like this...

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
 export class ApiService {
   private apiUrl = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=Your_APi_Key";

   constructor() {}
   getAPiUrl() {
      return this.apiUrl;
   }
 }
```

Thats it, when inside service you provide valid api-key then map is working fine and you need to enable maps inside of your google account in order to view it properly.

Comment: Thanks For you answer,but it still take the url from the `Appmodule` not the `constructor`

Comment: No, I have checked it out in my side, its working properly.

Comment: your demo is working fine, but when I tried to apply it in my project, it doesnt work

Comment: the value of  `apiToken.apiUrl` changed but the map works with forRoot value

Comment: share you code in stackblitz link. so that I can check it out , where its not working?

Comment: I did as you tell me, I'm using angular  5, is may that the problem?

Comment: I always got `Geocoding Service: You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs` if I didn't pass the url in forRoot()

Comment: even I inject the service in the main component (AppComponent) and it didn't work

Comment: just pass empty string in forRoot like this `forRoot({apiUrl: ''})` and then in component you can inject token

Comment: I added my code in stackbilitz and it's works propely : [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b89bvy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) , I think there's something going on my project